# Gets the list of all partition that I have in my phone + copy them

Tags: c#, android, adb

How can I get a list of all the partition that i have in my phone (Block list) + copy them outside my phone to external memory card.

I can implement this with ADB or #C.

Thanks,

Comment: Your phone has partitions? Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi, this phone is a regular phone with KitKat- 4.4.4. if i understand correctly (i am new at android), for every phone we have partition (BOOT, BOTA0, etc..).

Comment: `BOOT, BOTA0, etc.`. Really? Never saw such. Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi, the storage in every phone divided into partition. every partition can be with different file system. i want to know where every partition starts and where ends, and copied all of them.

Comment: That's no elaboration. You only repeat yourself. This will not bring you further.

Comment: Hello, i don't know much more..

Answer (score 0):

The partitioning scheme has nothing to do with Android. It's a part of [BSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_support_package) provided by the [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_a_chip) manufacturer (i.e. Qualcomm, Intel, Mediatek, etc).

There's no universal way of getting it.

Comment: How can i do it for MOTO-X phone?

Comment: All partitions accessible from AP will have `mmcblk0pXX` block devices created in `/dev/block`. For the list of partition names check `/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name`. You will need to have root access to copy the data.

Comment: Hi, i saw that i have also partition which name is: **mmcblk1pXX** there is any different?. what is the command that i needs to do for copy this partition completely? Also how can i know the _File system_ of this partition? what is **AP**?

Comment: By the way i have Root access.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to root your phone and use the 'parted' command or 'busybox mount' or 'busybox df -h' command.

Unfortunately the 'parted' command doesn't come with Android or busybox, but if you go to Google Playstore and download the ROM Manager app and then open the app, and update the App, the 'parted' command will appear in the following directory:

/data/data/com.koushikdutta.rommanager/files/parted

Then run the following command:

root# ./parted /dev/block/mmcblk0 print

```
# Model: MMC MAG4FB (sd/mmc)
# Disk /dev/block/mmcblk0: 15.8GB
# Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
# Partition Table: gpt
#
# Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name        Flags
#  0      /dev/block/mmcblk0 Whole Internal Storage
#  1      4194kB  8389kB  4194kB               BOTA0
#  2      8389kB  12.6MB  4194kB               BOTA1
#  3      12.6MB  33.6MB  21.0MB  ext4         EFS         (EFS)
#  4      33.6MB  37.7MB  4194kB               m9kefs1
# etc.
```

Hope this helps you out.